# How to programmatically list all devise routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I'm using devise to authenticate my users in my Rails 4.1.9 application.

I need to list all devise routes in a javascript file.

I tried to do something like this:

```
all_routes = Rails.application.routes.routes.map do |route|
    route.path.spec.to_s.gsub('(.:format)', '')
end
```

This simply prints all rails routes. How can I get only devise ones?

I tried to check the controllers, but I don't know how to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the routes controller to determine if the route belongs to a devise controller or not: `route.defaults[:controller]`, this might get tricky if you are customizing or skipping default routes for your own:

Once you have the controller, for example: `"devise/sessions"` it should be easy to ask if it `.starts_with? "devise"` or something similar. I hope this helps!

Comment: The second line above can be changed as follows: `route.path.spec.to_s.gsub('(.:format)', '') if route.defaults[:controller] && route.defaults[:controller].include?('devise')`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a reliable way. It should work even in the case of custom controllers.

```
# Ask devise what controllers is has mapped
devise_controllers = Devise.mappings.values.map do |mapping|
  mapping.controllers.map{|k, v| v}}
end.flatten.uniq
# Ask rails for the routes that resolve to devise controllers
Rails.application.routes.routes.select do |route|
  devise_controllers.include? route.defaults[:controller]
end
```